# I am having a error in namespace and "use" statement in php

Tags: php, namespaces

I am getting errors when I try to use Namespace and use statement in PHP like this.

**Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'demo\TestController' not found**

I have two files "TestController.php" and "Testing.php"

Demo\TestController.php

```
<?php
namespace Demo;
class TestController
{
  function show()
  {
    echo 'Here We Go';
  }
}
?>
```

Demo\Testing.php

```
<?php 
namespace Demo;
use Demo\TestController as Ninja;
$TestController = new Ninja();
$TestController->show();
?>
```

It is possible to add classes without require once & include.
Someone please give me a little guidance to figure it out the issue?

Comment: You need to include / require the class first. You can use an [autoloader](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php).

Comment: It is possible to add classes without require once & include

Comment: Still it gives same error.

Comment: Update your post with your updated code.

Comment: 1. You need to add the code in to the post not a comment. 2. You are still not including / requiring the file.

Comment: *"It is possible to add classes without require once & include"* - Fundamentally *no*. PHP cannot magically locate your files for you. You can make it *somewhat magical* by using an autoloader, but even that would need to be included at least once.

Comment: Thank you.Issue solve by using autoloader.

Comment: I can include once but not again and again